# Subversion - Unpredictable merge behavior

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning

I am merging some code from `<trunk>` to another branch of mine,  in SVN.

The first time I did this was like so:

```
cd /path-to-code/branches/branch_local
svn merge http://mydomain/svn/code/trunk
```

The first time I attempted the merge, there were several conflicts. It turns out that just accepting "theirs-conflict" (TC) several times was not adequate, as there were build failures after the merge. So, I just reverted my working copy via `svn revert -R .`, and re-attempted the merge. This time, though, there were no conflicts detected, and it appears that SVN just used "theirs-full" (TF) automatically. This seemed odd, so I deleted the folder/files that I was merging locally, and updated my working copy via `svn up`, and the same thing (theirs-full) occurred again.

I also noticed that when I postpone certain conflicts, and then attempt to do the SVN merge a second time, the conflicts are not noted the second merge attempt (they seem "stuck" in a postponed state).

What would I do to the force SVN to go back to step 1, where it notifies me of conflicts once more, as opposed to just automatically ignoring them and using "theirs-full" for conflict resolution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think about 2 versions:

1. You should do `check out` again into another directory.
2. You can go to root your working copy and do `svn cleanup` (just
   after `revert`)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I turns out that the local working copy was out of date. After the first update, the error was (of course) non-reproducible. Guess I lost track of my steps. Thanks!